# Disallowed Key Characters in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have studying about disallowed key characters error in codeigntier. But, I think I dont have those characters in my form. May be I may be mistaken.

**My Form**

```
    <div class="container_part">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row-fluid  maincontainer">

            <div class="mycontainer">
                <?php echo form_open('bookings/customerdetails'); ?>

                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span12 mainheading">

                        <hr>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row-fluid">

                        <div class="span6">

                            <div style="padding: 20px;">

                                <div>

                                    <select name="booking_form_customer_initial">

                                        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                                        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                                        <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>

                                <div>

                                    <input type="text" name="booking_form_customer_name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" class="span12" required="required" />

                                </div>

                                <div>

                                    <input type="text" name="booking_form_customer_phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" class="span12" required="required" />

                                </div>

                                <div>

                                    <input type="email" name="booking_form_customer_email" placeholder="Enter Email" class="span12" required="required" />

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span6">

                            <div class="control-group select optional booking_form_pick_up_method">
                                <label class="select optional control-label" for="booking_form_pick_up_method">Delivery method</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select class="select optional form-refesher" id="booking_form_pick_up_method" name="booking_form_pick_up_method" required="required">
                                        <option value="">Select Delivery method</option>
                                        <option value="in_store">self_pick_up</option>
                                        <option value="courier">courier</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-observe="#booking_form_pick_up_method" data-visible-when="in_store" style="display: none">
                                <div class="control-group select optional booking_form_pick_up_location">
                                    <label class="select optional control-label" for="booking_form_pick_up_location">Pick up location</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select class="select optional form-refesher" id="booking_form_pick_up_location" name="booking_form[pick_up_location]">
                                            <option value="1">Tsim Sha Tsui</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-observe="#booking_form_pick_up_method" data-visible-when="courier" style="display: none">
                                <div class="control-group string optional booking_form_pick_up_courier_name">
                                    <label class="string optional control-label" for="booking_form_pick_up_courier_name">Contact Person</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="string optional" id="booking_form_pick_up_courier_name" name="booking_form[pick_up_courier_name]" type="text" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group string optional booking_form_pick_up_courier_addr">
                                    <label class="string optional control-label" for="booking_form_pick_up_courier_addr">Delivery Address</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="string optional" id="booking_form_pick_up_courier_addr" name="booking_form[pick_up_courier_addr]"  type="text" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group tel optional booking_form_pick_up_courier_phone">
                                    <label class="tel optional control-label" for="booking_form_pick_up_courier_phone">Contact Phone</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="string tel optional" id="booking_form_pick_up_courier_phone" name="booking_form[pick_up_courier_phone]"  type="tel" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group select optional booking_form_drop_off_method">
                                <label class="select optional control-label" for="booking_form_drop_off_method">Return Method</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <select class="select optional form-refesher" id="booking_form_drop_off_method" name="booking_form_drop_off_method" required="required">
                                        <option value="">Select Return method</option>
                                        <option value="in_store">self_drop_off</option>
                                        <option value="courier">courier</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-observe="#booking_form_drop_off_method" data-visible-when="in_store" style="display: none">
                                <div class="control-group select optional booking_form_drop_off_location">
                                    <label class="select optional control-label" for="booking_form_drop_off_location">Drop off location</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select class="select optional form-refesher" id="booking_form_drop_off_location" name="booking_form[drop_off_location]">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option value="1">Tsim Sha Tsui</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-observe="#booking_form_drop_off_method" data-visible-when="courier" style="display: none">
                                <div class="control-group string optional booking_form_drop_off_courier_name">
                                    <label class="string optional control-label" for="booking_form_drop_off_courier_name">Contact  Person</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="string optional" id="booking_form_drop_off_courier_name" name="booking_form[drop_off_courier_name]" type="text" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group string optional booking_form_drop_off_courier_addr">
                                    <label class="string optional control-label" for="booking_form_drop_off_courier_addr">Return Address</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="string optional" id="booking_form_drop_off_courier_addr" name="booking_form[drop_off_courier_addr]" type="text" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group tel optional booking_form_drop_off_courier_phone">
                                    <label class="tel optional control-label" for="booking_form_drop_off_courier_phone">Contact Phone</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input class="string tel optional" id="booking_form_drop_off_courier_phone" name="booking_form[drop_off_courier_phone]" type="tel" value="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    Customer Remarks
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group string optional booking_form_remarks">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <textarea class="string optional input-large span8" id="booking_form_remarks" name="booking_form_remarks]" ></textarea>
                                    </div>                              </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="row-fluid" id="transaction-details" style="position: relative;">
                        <div style="padding:25px;">

                            <div id="cart_content">
                                <?php echo $this->view('shop/cart.php'); ?>
                            </div>


                            <input type="submit" name="customer_details_submit_btn" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" />

                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>




                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

---

**My controller controlling the validation is below.**

```
function customerdetails() {


    $customer_v_rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'booking_form_customer_name',
            'label' => 'Full Name',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'booking_form_customer_phone',
            'label' => 'Phone',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'booking_form_customer_email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'booking_form_pick_up_method',
            'label' => 'Delivery Method',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'booking_form_pick_up_method',
            'label' => 'Delivery Method',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'booking_form_drop_off_method',
            'label' => 'Return Method',
            'rules' => 'required'
        )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($customer_v_rules);


    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $name = $this->input->$this->input->post('booking_form_customer_name');
        $phone = $this->input->post('booking_form_customer_phone');
        $email = $this->input->post('booking_form_customer_email');

        $remarks = $this->input->post('booking_form_remarks');

        echo 'OK';
    } else {

        $this->customer_details_initial_task();

//$this->show_products_session_array();

        $data = array('page_title' => 'Customer Section');

        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Customer Section');
        $this->template->write_view('meta', 'templates/wiyo/partials/meta', $meta, TRUE);
        $this->template->write_view('header', 'templates/wiyo/partials/header', $data, TRUE);
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'customerdetails', $data, TRUE);
        $this->template->render();
    }


//$this -> output -> enable_profiler(TRUE);
}
```

**My Config file**

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['uri_allowed_chars'] = 'a-z?';    
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

---

Helping hands are appreciated.

Comment: I got my answer. It was problem with '[' and ']'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a possible problem. Look at name of your textarea "]" must be a disallowed character.

```
<textarea class="string optional input-large span8" id="booking_form_remarks" name="booking_form_remarks]" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step1.** Search for function _clean_input_keys on /system/core/Input.php

**Step2.** Modify this line:

```
exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’);
```

to:

```
exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’ .  $str);
```

**Step3.** Refresh page to see the characters which generate the error

**Step4.** If you need to add those characters into the exception list, just add to this line

```
if ( ! preg_match(“/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$|/i”, $str))
```

I add `|` (pipe) character on the example above.

Comment: Doing that: `exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’ .  $str);` help me to figure out the error... I couldn't see it! It was an accented word: "Sábado"